# How to create a button that adds InputFields when clicked?

Tags: gui-construction, button

I would like to create a button 'ADD' that creates a new InputField each time the user clicks it.

I have tried something like this so far:

```
CreateWindow[
 DialogNotebook[
  TextCell["Click on + button to add more cells"]
   Button["ADD", InputField["Enter new input here"]]
 ]
]
```

The above method does not work. What would be a good and simple workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 5):

```
cnt = {};
i=0;                                        (*added*)
CreateWindow[DialogNotebook[{
   "Click on ADD button to add more cells:",
   Dynamic@Column@cnt,
   Button["ADD", 
   i++;                                     (*added*)
   nm=ToExpression["a"<>ToString@i];        (*added*)
   AppendTo[cnt, 
    InputField[Dynamic@Evaluate@nm,         (*updated*)
               FieldHint->"Enter new input here"]]]   
   }, WindowSize -> 250, 
  WindowElements -> {"VerticalScrollBar", "StatusArea"}]]
```

[image]

The array of inputfields stores data in specially created variables `a1, a2,....ax`.

Comment: This almost does what I need. The problem that I face now is that the data that I input into those fields go only in to single variable and every time something new is entered, the variable updates. Is there a way to have the list of inputs to the fields stored in a list?

Comment: look at the updated version

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this resource function:
https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ListInputField

You can download the source notebook to see how it works.